# OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I've been waiting for Google to verify my OAuth consent screen for several months. This means that my functionality is restricted. The message that I am getting on the admin panel is...

> Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several
>   days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.

Is there some way of following this up or checking for any issues with my application?

Comment: This month Google made changes to which scopes are allowed and is not approving a lot of apps. What scopes are you requesting?

Comment: email, profile, openid, yt-analytics-monetary.readonly, youtubepartner-channel-audit, youtube, youtube.force-ssl, youtubepartner, youtube.readonly, youtube.upload, yt-analytics.readonly

I'm also waiting for a response from Google support so I'll see what their feedback is.

Comment: The first three are fine. You will not have problems getting approved for those. However, I don't know about YouTube, I have not created OAuth Clients for that service. TIP: Create several OAuth  Client IDs with different levels of scopes. This will help you understand which ones Google has an issue with for your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to contact G Suite Support with the G Suite APIs team, they can help you to speed up the verification process. You can check this article https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en for more information.

There has been some changes and categorized new scopes as restricted or sensitive, also if you add, remove or update any scope within your consent screen you will be asked for a new verification process.

The verification process should not take months. The G Suite API team will help you to find the best solution since they have the chance to contact the Trust and safety team who will review your verification.

For a faster verification, ensure that your app complies with our policy. For more information, see https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-requirements. And provide with all possible information like videos using your application, things like that.

Comment: Thanks Mario - looks like there was an email I missed and the support team resent. Basically confirming that I wanted to include an icon with my consent form. That's all been done and hopefully the approval will come through soon!

Comment: I am glad to know that. Please consider accepting it as an answer if that resolves your inquiry, so that can help others to find the best solution. it is always a pleasure to help here. Hopefully the approval will be completed soon.

Comment: An email contact for G Suite support would be helpful. The email responses you get back from the OAuth consent team are long, pre formulated emails that don't tell you what you are failing to do.